# SolrCloud 5.1.0 Replica

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have a SolrCloud running on Solr 5.1.0 which consist of a set of powerful machines for searches and updates.

I have a set of additional and slower machines which are supposed to be only replica. These machines do not receive any direct traffic.

However, the logfiles of the slower machines show a lot of query traffic originating the other nodes.

I want the slow replicas for recovery only, they should not process any searches.

Is there a possibility to configure this behaviour in SolrCloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Solrcloud does not provide a mechanism by which a node participates in replication, but is not a candidate for per-shard fan-out queries.

That said...

- You can do this with master/slave replication.
- If all the shards for your collection(s) are on every node, then the preferLocalShards=true parameter might accomplish the same thing. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Distributed+Requests

Comment: Thank you. `preferLocalShards=true` looked interesting but wouldn't it void the advantages of sharding? I could still split into shards but since every shard would need to be on every node I could as well just have replicas of one huge shard on several nodes

Comment: Yes, you could. It depends on why you're sharding. You tend to see degraded performance past a certain size. It's hard to give numbers because indexes vary a lot, but for example I try to shard such that no shard has more than 100M docs.